# Why can't I set a class' properties in it's parent's constructor? (php)

Tags: php, class, parent-child, extends, php-5.2

I've been following the no-framework php tutorial (related chapter here: https://github.com/PatrickLouys/no-framework-tutorial/blob/master/07-inversion-of-control.md). And while extending it, as an abbreviated example, everything works fine when I'm instantiating the various properties of the class:

```
use Http\Request;

class User extends Super_user
{
    private $request; 

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->request = $request;
    }
}
```

However when I try and set the request in the parent I seem to get the error: Argument 1 passed to Namespace\Controllers\Super_user::__construct() must be an instance of Namespace\Template\Request, none given, called in...

```
class User extends Super_user
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

...

```
use Http\Request;

class Super_user
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated from someone who is fairly new to PHP...

Comment: Looks like your mixing up namespaces? Your using HTTP\Request. However the error says it wants `must be an instance of Namespace\Template\Request`.  Maybe not, I haven't dove very deeply into PHP Namespaces yet (hooray for working on legacy code</sarcasm>)

Answer (score 1):

As Super_user class requires an Request object in its constructor.
You should declare your User's constructor method like this

```
public function __construct(Request $request)
{
    parent::__construct($request);  // Pass $request object to Parent's method
    $this->request = $request;
}
```